# Puppeteer: save sessionStorage and localStorage

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

Can Puppeteer store values from sessionStorage and localStorage on a disk and use them next time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. I used node-persist together with Puppeteer as a solution. You can use it like the following.

```
const storage = require('node-persist');

// Set Local Storage
storage.initSync();
var data = {
    "token": storage.getItemSync("token")
};
page.evaluate((data) => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
}, data);

// Get Local Storage
page.evaluate(() => {
    return {
        "token": localStorage.getItem("token")
    };
}).then((data) => {
    storage.initSync();
    storage.setItemSync("token", data.token);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand. You can access localStorage from node like it's a global var? localStorage doesn't exist in node...